# Is it possible to make a posynomial concave using a change of variables?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, change-of-variable, geometric-programming

**Update**

This question has an answer [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/11009/7263).

---

Consider the following posynomial with respect to the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k x_1^{a_{1k}} x_2^{a_{2k}} \cdots x_n^{a_{nk}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{a_{ik}}
\end{align}
$$
Using the change of variables $\tilde x_i = \log x_i$, such that $x_i = e^{\tilde x_i}$, we get the following expression
$$
\begin{align}
f(\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n e^{\tilde x_i a_{ik}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde x_i a_{ik}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \exp(\log(c_k)) \cdot \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde x_i a_{ik}\right] \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \exp\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde x_i a_{ik} + \log(c_k)\right]
\end{align}
$$
This expression is convex with respect to $\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n$ (see [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eee127/sp21/livebook/def_lse_fcn.html) for a proof). My question is: does there exist a similar change of variables such that the resulting expression is *concave* with respect to $\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n$? That is, does there exist functions $g_1,\dots,g_n$ such that $f(\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n)$, where $\tilde x_i = g_i(x_i)$, is concave with respect to $\tilde x_1,\dots,\tilde x_n$?

Comment: Consider the special case of $f(x) = x$ and $\tilde x = -\frac 1x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair this seems to be the special case when $K = 1, c_1 = 1,$ and $n = 1$. However, I don't think this generalizes well when $K > 1$ and $n > 1$. When I perform this substitution, I get $$\sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \left(-\frac{1}{\tilde x_i}\right)^{a_{ik}}$$ which seems to be convex or concave depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. I'm interested in a change of variables where concavity is independent of $n$.

Comment: $-\frac 1x$ was just a handy concave function I grabbed for the example. Any other concave function would do. That special case is not as special as you claim, you yourself even admit, as you recognize that it results in concavity for all odd $n$. You should put more thought into why that is. What restrictions are you demanding for the "similar" change in variables? Do they really all have to be the same function of the $x_i$? $\tilde x_1 = -\frac 1{x_1}, \tilde x_i = x_i, i > 1$ will work for any $n$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see what you mean. No, not all the change of variables need to be the same. The one you mentioned is a good idea actually. I'll think about this a bit more and get back to you on this (if you have the time, of course).

Comment: @PaulSinclair after thinking about it a bit more, I realized that your substitution may not necessarily work. That is, I get $$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\tilde x_1}\right)^{a_{1k}} \cdot \prod_{i=2}^n \left(\tilde x_i\right)^{a_{ik}} &= \sum_{k=1}^K c_k \cdot \left(-1\right)^{a_{1k}} \cdot \frac{1}{\tilde x_1^{a_{1k}}} \cdot \prod_{i=2}^n \left(\tilde x_i\right)^{a_{ik}}\end{align}$$ and so concavity now depends on $a_{1k}$, whereas in my question, convexity was independent of $a_{1k}$.